# Формат даты в sql?

Tags: php, datetime, sqlite3

товарищи!

Вопрос такой:

```
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES (:id, :title, datetime(), :text)', $params)
```

сохраняет дату в формате `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, а нужно вот так `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss`. Как реализовать?

Comment: Очевидно что не нужно. А то что нужно - это получить дату из БД и отформатировать как надо на выводе.

Comment: А вот об этом то я и не подумал. Спасибо, вопрос снят :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А можно вот так: `strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")`. Но целесообразно так, как предложил товарищ u_mulder :)